# Unable to get output in Verilog simulation of digital clock

Tags: verilog, simulation, clock, xilinx-ise

I want to design a seconds counter, which will count from 0 to 59, using Mod10COunter and Mod6Counter. I am trying to test the output using a testbench. The clock generated is perfect. However, the output is always 'X'. This is the code for the seconds counter.

```
module generateSec(clk, reset, s1, s2, min_en);
input wire clk, reset;
 output reg [3:0] s1, s2;
 output reg min_en;

 wire enable;
 Mod10Counter sec1 (.clk(clk), .out(s1), .en_out(enable), .rst(reset));
 Mod6Counter sec2 (.clk(enable), .out(s2), .en_out(min_en), .rst(reset));
endmodule
```

I have written the modules used as below.

```
module Mod10Counter(clk, out, en_out, rst);
input clk, rst;
output reg [3:0] out;
output reg en_out;

always @(posedge clk or rst) begin

    if (rst) begin
        out<=4'b0000;
        en_out<=1'b0;
        end
    else if (out == 4'b1001) begin
        out <= 4'b0000;
        en_out <= 1'b1;
       end      
    else begin
    out <= out+1;
    en_out <= 1'b0;
       end
end
endmodule

module Mod6Counter(clk, out, en_out, rst);
input clk, rst;
 output reg [3:0] out;
 output reg en_out;

always @(posedge clk or rst) begin

    if (rst) out<=4'b0000;
    else if (out == 4'b0101) begin
        out <= 4'b0000;
        en_out <= 1'b1;
    end     
    else begin
    out <= out+1;
    en_out <= 1'b0;
    end
end 
endmodule
```

The test-bench for the generateSec is as follows:

```
`timescale 1ms / 1ps

 module generateSec_test;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg reset;

// Outputs
wire [3:0] s1;
wire [3:0] s2;
wire min_en;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
generateSec uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .s1(s1), 
    .s2(s2), 
    .min_en(min_en)
);

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #500 clk=~clk;
end

initial begin
    reset = 1;
    #550;
    reset =0;
end 
endmodule
```

I am pasting the screenshot of the output here for the problem mentioned above.
[Output of Verilog simulation of generateSec-testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao5dB.png)

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but s1, s2 and min_en in generateSec should be wire not reg, as they are driven by a cell output.

Comment: i cannot reproduce it. I do not get 'x', it works ok in simulation. it could be an issue with the wave dumping or a race condition. One suggestion is to replace `@(posedge clk or rst)` with `@(posedge clk or posedge rst) `

Answer (score 0):

With Verilog, a module port cannot drive a `reg`. SystemVerilog does allow this.

To stay with Verilog, in `generateSec`, change:

```
 output reg [3:0] s1, s2;
 output reg min_en;
```

To:

```
 output [3:0] s1, s2;
 output min_en;
```

Alternatively, if your tool-set supports SystemVerilog, then you can change the file extension from `.v` to `.sv` and you can leave it as `output reg` (`output` or `output logic` would be preferred). To the best of my knowledge, Xilinx's ISE only supports up to Verilog 2001. Xilinx's Vivado does.

As Serge metioned, `@(posedge clk or rst)` should be `@(posedge clk or posedge rst)`.

Also `en_out` should be reset in `Mod6Counter`.